# Postsharp and log4net and log4postsharp

Tags: log4net, postsharp, log4postsharp

I stumbled upon log4postsharp [site](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp) which is a great tool that uses postsharp for injecting log4net statements into your code at compile time.

The current version of log4postsharp uses Postsharp 1.0 which has some limitations. Does anyone know if there is somewhere a compiled version of log4postsharp that uses Postsharp 1.5 available?

Answer (score 0):

The project has been upgraded to PostSharp 1.5.